# 404 when I save my extension in the configuration menu

Tags: php, xml, magento

i'm new to developing extensions for Magento.
I created an admin extension. The configuration menu can be accessed in the system-> configuration - menu.

I created a small extension where you can enter your email and save it. The menu appears, but when I save my configuration I get a 404 error.

I created under Companyname\Modulename the folders Helper, Model and etc.

The helper contains the necessary Data.php file. 
The etc contains 3 xml files: adminhtml, config and system.

You can see the xml here: http://pastebin.com/ZqiuqVAB

Any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to clear cache en sessions and login again?

It could also be a problem with your ACL.
Check this out:

http://alanstorm.com/magento_acl_authentication

Looking at your adminhtml.xml, I'm missing outer tags. Wrap your adminhtml.xml between:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
```

// Your adminhtml.xml code

```
</config>
```

Comment: I tried to clear cache and session. It didn't solve the issue. I thought about an ACL issue mysfelf, but the things I tried from your link, didn't solve the issue for me : /

Answer (score 0):

Please update below code in your `system.xml`

```
                           <Emailexport_input translate="label">
                            <label>E-Mail: </label>
                            <comment>Die E-Mail Adresse, an der täglich der Bestellungsexport versendet werden soll.</comment>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>220</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </Emailexport_input>
```

Let me know if you have any query

Answer (score 0):

please do the following change in your system.xml

```
<Emailexport_domain translate="label comment">
    <label>E-Mail: </label>
    <comment><![CDATA[Die E-Mail Adresse, an der t&auml;glich der Bestellungsexport versendet werden soll.]]></comment>
    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
    <sort_order>220</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</Emailexport_domain>
```

And change

```
<dgroup translate="label" module="Emailexport">
```

with

```
<dgroup translate="label" module="emailexport">
```

Comment: The first part doesn't solve the issue. When I change the second part, I get an exception when I open the system -> configuration menu : /